# Add Connection is empty-External Content Type

Tags: 2013, external-content-type

When I click on Add Connection the drop down list comes empty. What should I do? Why can't I see the drop down list?

Comment: Did you try to check the BCS service and see if the connections are there?
the service is located in "Central admin" under "Application Management" in "Manage service applications"

Comment: Yes I did. BDC,PerformancePoint, Claims to Windows Token Service are started and in App Man Services I created Secure Store and BDC.

Comment: Let's check if it's a permission problem, are you logged as farm admin?

Comment: I checked. Everythings ok. Yes I'm a farm admin.